# Can I use bindParam always?

Tags: php, pdo

I see so many people using "execute(array [...]" in their SQL methods, I always used

`execute->bindParam('[...]', $string);`

Can I still using bindParam? If no, when should I use it? Thanks

Comment: Yes if you like it

Comment: Why did you accept the wrong answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would only use BindParam to get data out of the query, or if I am actually using the binding e.g. updating the bound variable and then re-calling execute, which is the point of the prepared statement.

If you have a lot (N) of parameters, and they are only one-off unchanging inputs, it's arguably more efficient to simply use the execute array, rather than calling N +1 function calls. (By arguably, I mean it's probably a micro-optimisation compared to your query speed.)

From a simplicity perspective, why go to all the trouble of binding (and risking complexities due to the references) if are not using the mechanism?

Both bind and execute array will provide the same security protection, there is no additional benefit there I know of.

Binding might be more readable - i.e. it's easier to see what is bound to what than the implicit order of the execute array, especially if you are binding to `?` not named labels.

I review code with what I feel are "spurious" bindings and I do usually *feel like* rejecting it and asking them to refactor to a simple execute + array, but then I usually don't bother. I think that shows it's close to being a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

Also as a third parameter you can specify the data type. That's the advantage of using `bindParam()` over executing array.

```
$sql->bindParam(':key', 23, PDO::PARAM_INT);//telling pdo that's it is integer type.
```

With executing array,  you can't specify type

```
$sql->execute([':key' => 23]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you should, it helps you dealing with unwanted quotes issues when adding rich text data and help you to prevent SQL Injection attack

Comment: Can you provide a reference that the execute array data is less well protected than the bound variables?

Comment: @scipilot come on, he just didn't understand the question at all. Sadly, this wrong answer cannot be deleted but at least should be downvoted